# How can I understand "(.) . (.)"?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

I believe I understand `fmap . fmap` for Functors, but on functions it's hurting my head for months now.

I've seen that you can just apply the definition of `(.)` to `(.) . (.)`, but I've forgot how to do that.
When I try it myself it always turns out wrong:

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
(.) (.) (.) = \x -> (.) ((.) x)
\x f -> (.) ((.) x) f
\x f y  -> (((.)(f y)) x)
\x f y g-> (((.)(f y) g) x)
\x f y g-> ((f (g y)) x)
\x f y g-> ((f (g y)) x):: t2 -> (t1 -> t2 -> t) -> t3 -> (t3 -> t1) -> t
```

If "just applying the definition" is the only way of doing it, how did anybody come up with `(.) . (.)`?
There must be some deeper understanding or intuition I'm missing.

Comment: @Will Ness You are right.. :P

Comment: @WillNess: The Owl-With-Glasses Combinator

Comment: @amindfv That's what it is..!!

Comment: If you understand `fmap . fmap`, well, just specialize both `fmap`s to the `(->) e` functor and you're done. ;-)

Comment: @DanielWagner Yep, but I lacked something else too, I'm not sure what, but the various answers helped. Sadly I can only tick one Answer :/

Comment: I just call it `compose2`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also use your understanding of `fmap . fmap`.

If you have two `Functor`s `foo` and `bar`, then

```
fmap . fmap :: (a -> b)  ->  foo (bar a)    ->   foo (bar b)
```

`fmap . fmap` takes a function and produces an induced function for the composition of the two `Functor`s.

Now, for any type `t`, `(->) t` is a `Functor`, and the `fmap` for that `Functor` is `(.)`.

So `(.) . (.)` is `fmap . fmap` for the case where the two `Functor`s are `(->) s` and `(->) t`, and thus

```
(.) . (.) :: (a -> b) -> ((->) s) ((->) t a) -> ((->) s) ((->) t b)
          =  (a -> b) -> (s -> (t -> a))     -> (s -> (t -> b))
          =  (a -> b) -> (s ->  t -> a )     -> (s ->  t -> b )
```

it "composes" a function `f :: a -> b` with a function of two arguments, `g :: s -> t -> a`,

```
((.) . (.)) f g = \x y -> f (g x y)
```

That view also makes it clear that, and how, the pattern extends to functions taking more arguments,

```
(.)             :: (a -> b) -> (s ->           a) -> (s ->           b)
(.) . (.)       :: (a -> b) -> (s -> t ->      a) -> (s -> t ->      b)
(.) . (.) . (.) :: (a -> b) -> (s -> t -> u -> a) -> (s -> t -> u -> b)
```

etc.

Comment: So I could say that `foo (bar a)` is a function of a function?! Ahh :)

Comment: @FabianGerhardt `foo` and `bar` here are two *type* variables.  `foo(bar a)` denotes a *type* of "a function from `s` to a function from `t` to `a`". It will only be a type of a *function of a function*, if `s` were to denote a function type, but that's extraneous.

Answer (score 39):

Coming up with `(.) . (.)` is actually pretty straightforward, it's the intuition behind what it does that is quite tricky to understand.

`(.)` gets you very far when rewriting expression into the "pipe" style computations (think of `|` in shell). However, it becomes awkward to use once you try to compose a function that takes multiple arguments with a function that only takes one. As an example, let's have a definition of `concatMap`:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f xs = concat (map f xs)
```

Getting rid of `xs` is just a standard operation:

```
concatMap f = concat . map f
```

However, there's no "nice" way of getting rid of `f`. This is caused by the fact, that `map` takes two arguments and we'd like to apply `concat` on its final result.

You can of course apply some pointfree tricks and get away with just `(.)`:

```
concatMap f = (.) concat (map f)
concatMap f = (.) concat . map $ f
concatMap = (.) concat . map
concatMap = (concat .) . map
```

But alas, readability of this code is mostly gone. Instead, we introduce a new combinator, that does exactly what we need: apply the second function to the *final result* of first one.

```
-- .: is fairly standard name for this combinator
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
(f .: g) x y = f (g x y)

concatMap = concat .: map
```

Fine, that's it for motivation. Let's get to the pointfree business.

```
(.:) = \f g x y -> f (g x y)
     = \f g x y -> f ((g x) y)
     = \f g x y -> f . g x $ y
     = \f g x   -> f . g x
```

Now, here comes the interesting part. This is yet another of the pointfree tricks that usually helps when you get stuck: we rewrite `.` into its prefix form and try to continue from there.

```
     = \f g x   -> (.) f (g x)
     = \f g x   -> (.) f . g $ x
     = \f g     -> (.) f . g
     = \f g     -> (.) ((.) f) g
     = \f       -> (.) ((.) f)
     = \f       -> (.) . (.) $ f
     =             (.) . (.)
```

As for intuition, there's this [very nice article](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators) that you should read. I'll paraphrase the part about `(.)`:

Let's think again about what our combinator should do: it should apply `f` to the *result* of *result* of `g` (I've been using *final result* in the part before on purpose, it's really what you get when you fully apply - modulo unifying type variables with another function type - the `g` function, *result* here is just application `g x` for some `x`).

What it means for us to apply `f` to the *result* of `g`? Well, once we apply `g` to some value, we'll take the result and apply `f` to it. Sounds familiar: that's what `(.)` does.

```
result :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
result = (.)
```

Now, it turns out that composition (our *of* word) of those combinators is just a function composition, that is:

```
(.:) = result . result -- the result of result
```

Comment: I really like this answer and it helped me. I would tick this one too if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution diverges when you introduce `y`. It should be

```
\x f y -> ((.) ((.) x) f) y     :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
\x f y z -> ((.) ((.) x) f) y z :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
\x f y z -> ((.) x (f y)) z     :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
-- Or alternately:
\x f y z -> (x . f y) z         :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
\x f y z -> (x (f y z))         :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
```

Which matches the original type signature: `(.) . (.) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d`

(It's easiest to do the expansion in ghci, where you can check each step with `:t expression`)

**Edit:**

The deeper intution is this:

`(.)` is simply defined as

```
\f g -> \x -> f (g x)
```

Which we can simplify to

```
\f g x -> f (g x)
```

So when you supply it two arguments, it's curried and still needs another argument to resolve.
Each time you use `(.)` with 2 arguments, you create a "need" for one more argument.

`(.) . (.)` is of course just `(.) (.) (.)`, so let's expand it:

```
(\f0 g0 x0 -> f0 (g0 x0)) (\f1 g1 x1 -> f1 (g1 x1)) (\f2 g2 x2 -> f2 (g2 x2))
```

We can beta-reduce on `f0` and `g0` (but we don't have an `x0`!):

```
\x0 -> (\f1 g1 x1 -> f1 (g1 x1)) ((\f2 g2 x2 -> f2 (g2 x2)) x0)
```

Substitute the 2nd expression for `f1`...

```
\x0 -> \g1 x1 -> ((\f2 g2 x2 -> f2 (g2 x2)) x0) (g1 x1)
```

Now it "flips back"! (beta-reduction on `f2`):
This is the interesting step - `x0` is substituted for `f2` -- This means that `x`, which could have been data, is instead a function.
*This* is what `(.) . (.)` provides -- the "need" for the extra argument.

```
\x0 -> \g1 x1 -> (\g2 x2 -> x0 (g2 x2)) (g1 x1)
```

This is starting to look normal...
Let's beta-reduce a last time (on `g2`):

```
\x0 -> \g1 x1 -> (\x2 -> x0 ((g1 x1) x2))
```

So we're left with simply

```
\x0 g1 x1 x2 -> x0 ((g1 x1) x2)
```

, where the arguments are nicely still in order.

Comment: really, this is so much simpler [with the combinatory equations](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/5016202). Really. :) Isn't it? (I picked this up from Davie, "Introduction to Functional Programming Systems Using Haskell").

Comment: @WillNess It definitely is simpler, but I find it easier to understand with all the arguments flying around. That looks like a really good book, though! I hadn't heard of it before.

Comment: it's a bit outdated, but has its *"early days"* charm. It's don't got Monads, though, AFAIR.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is what I get when I do a slightly more incremental expansion

```
(.) f g   = \x -> f (g x)
(.) . g   = \x -> (.) (g x)
          = \x -> \y -> (.) (g x) y
          = \x -> \y -> \z -> (g x) (y z)
          = \x y z -> (g x) (y z)
(.) . (.) = \x y z -> ((.) x) (y z)
          = \x y z -> \k -> x (y z k)
          = \x y z k -> x (y z k)
```

Which, according to ghci has the correct type

```
Prelude> :t (.) . (.)
(.) . (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c
Prelude> :t \x y z k -> x (y z k)
\x y z k -> x (y z k)
  :: (t1 -> t) -> (t2 -> t3 -> t1) -> t2 -> t3 -> t
Prelude>
```

While I don't know the origins of this combinator, it is likely that it was
developed for use in combinatory logic, where you work strictly with combinators,
so you can't define things using more convenient lambda expressions. There may be
some intuition that goes with figuring these things out, but I haven't found it.
Most likely, you would develop some level of intuition if you had to do it enough.

Answer (score 3):

It's easiest to write *equations*, [combinators-style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system), instead of lambda-expressions: `a b c = (\x -> ... body ...)` is equivalent to `a b c x = ... body ...`, and vice versa, provided that `x` does not appear among `{a,b,c}`. So,

```
-- _B = (.)  

_B f g x = f (g x)
_B _B _B f g x y = _B (_B f) g x y
                 = (_B f) (g x) y
                 = _B f (g x) y
                 = f ((g x) y)
                 = f (g x y)
```

You discover this if, given `f (g x y)`, you want to convert it [into a combinatory form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) (get rid of all the parentheses and variable repetitions). Then you apply patterns corresponding to the combinators' definitions, hopefully tracing this derivation backwards. This is much less mechanical/automatic though.