# Haskell function composition, type of (.)(.) and how it's presented

Tags: haskell, types, operator-keyword, function-composition

So i know that:

```
(.) = (f.g) x = f (g x)
```

And it's type is (B->C)->(A->B)->A->C
But what about:

```
(.)(.) = _? = _?
```

How this is represented? I thought of:

```
(.)(.) = (f.g)(f.g)x = f(g(f(g x))) // this
(.)(.) = (f.g.h)x = f(g(h x)) // or this
```

But as far as i tried to get type of it, it's not correct to what GHCi tells me.
So what are both "_?"

Also - what does function/operator **$** do?

Comment: I wonder whether we should add a tag for the name of `(.)(.)` and `(.).(.)`?

Answer (score 14):

First off, you're being sloppy with your notation.

```
(.) = (f.g) x = f (g x)  -- this isn't true
```

What is true:

```
(.) f g x = (f.g) x = f (g x)
(.) = \f g x -> f (g x)
```

And its type is given by

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
       -- n.b. lower case, because they're type *variables*
```

Meanwhile

```
(.)(.) :: (a -> b -> d) -> a -> (c -> b) -> c -> d
          -- I renamed the variables ghci gave me
```

Now let's work out

```
(.)(.) = (\f' g' x' -> f' (g' x')) (\f g x -> f (g x))
       = \g' x' -> (\f g x -> f (g x)) (g' x')
       = \g' x' -> \g x -> (g' x') (g x)
       = \f y -> \g x -> (f y) (g x)
       = \f y g x -> f y (g x)
       = \f y g x -> (f y . g) x
       = \f y g -> f y . g
```

---

And `($)`?

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

`($)` is just function application. But whereas function application via juxtaposition is high precedence, function application via `($)` is low precedence.

```
square $ 1 + 2 * 3 = square (1 + 2 * 3)
square 1 + 2 * 3 = (square 1) + 2 * 3  -- these lines are different
```

Comment: It's all fine, but lets say i want to use (.)(.) operator in GHCi.
If i want to use (.) i say:
(.) function1 function2 parameters_for_f2
but if i want to use (.)(.) what would i have to write next?

Comment: `(.)(.)` isn't really an operator, it's an expression. You could write `(.) (.) f y g`.

Comment: That's the problem. If i write:
(.) (.) succ succ succ 3 i get error.
Also if i write:
(.) (.) id succ succ 3 it now magicly works but id and succ hase same arity.

Comment: @RippeR no, `id` is polymorphic while `succ` is only defined on enums.  Since `a -> b` is not an enum, `(.)(.) succ succ succ 3` does not make sense.  `(.) (.) id = (.)`

Comment: So if:
(.)(.) f g h _____ is not equal to
(f.g.h) ___, that what is this euqal to? (using it in infix form)?

Comment: @RippeR `(.) (.) f y g x = f y (g x)`, as in my answer.

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if you woudn't name funtion as 'y' but... maybe 'h'? :>

So now i can use: id succ (succ 5) in example, but i still cant figure out why first one has to be polymorphic and not any type. 
I still can do (succ.succ.succ) 3 and it gives me 6.

Lets say that i have: f g (h x) does that mean that h take's x as argument, g takes h(x) as argument and f takes g (not g(h(x))) as argument? It would explain it, since id can take function as well as number, but succ can't take function.

Comment: @RippeR `y` is *not* a function. Read again the type signature I gave for `(.)(.)`.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if i understood at least 10% of that... ;)
I think it's too much for me, at least for now... It's a middle of the night and it's just to strage for me (someone whos all programming experience is in C++ and similiar languages).

Buth thanks anyway, i will try to get something out of it tommorrow (which is latter today for me now ;)).

Btw. do you know good tutorial or book for begginers (or someone who programmed in C++/C#/Java/PHP etc.)? You sound very good at subject so maybe you know something good. ;)

Answer (score 7):

As dave4420 mentions,

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So what is the type of `(.) (.)`? dave4420 skips that part, so here it is: `(.)` accepts a value of type `b -> c` as its first argument, so

```
(.) :: (   b     ->       c             ) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) ::  (d -> e) -> ((f -> d) -> f -> e)
```

so we have `b ~ d->e` and `c ~ (f -> d) -> f -> e`, and the resulting type of `(.)(.)` is `(a -> b) -> a -> c`. Substituting, we get

```
(a -> d -> e) -> a -> (f -> d) -> f -> e
```

Renaming, we get `(a -> b -> c) -> a -> (d -> b) -> d -> c`. This is a function `f` that expects a binary function `g`, a value `x`, a unary function `h` and another value `y`:

```
f g x h y = g x (h y)
```

That's the only way this type can be realized: `g x :: b -> c`, `h y :: b` and so `g x (h y) :: c`, as needed.

Of course in Haskell, a "unary" function is such that expects one *or more* arguments; similarly a "binary" function is such that expects two *or more* arguments. But not less than two (so using e.g. `succ` is out of the question).

---

We can also tackle this by writing equations, *[combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic)-style*<sup>1</sup>. [Equational reasoning is *easy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030418/849891):

```
(.) (.) x y z w q = 
((.) . x) y z w q =
(.) (x y) z w q =
(x y . z) w q =
x y (z w) q
```

We just throw as much variables as needed into the mix and then apply the definition back and forth. `q` here was an extra, so we can throw it away and get the final definition,

```
_BB x y z w = x y (z w)
```

(coincidentally, `(.)` is known as [**B**-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinators_B.2C_C)).

---

<sup>1</sup> `a b c = (\x -> ... body ...)` is equivalent to `a b c x = ... body ...`, and vice versa, provided that `x` does not appear among `{a,b,c}`.